# Running numpy from cygwin

Tags: python, numpy

I am running a windows machine have installed Python 2.5.  I also used the windows installer to install NumPy.

This all works great when I run the Python (command line) tool that comes with Python.

However, if I run cygwin and then run Python from within, it cannot find the numpy package.

What environment variable do I need to set? What value should it be set to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin comes with its own version of Python, so it's likely that you have two Python installs on your system; one that installed under Windows and one which came with Cygwin.

To test this, try opening a bash prompt in Cygwin and typing `which python` to see where the Python executable is located.  If it says `/cygdrive/c/Python25/python.exe` or something similar then you'll know you're running the Windows executable.  If you see `/usr/local/bin/python` or something like that, then you'll know that you're running the Cygwin version.

I recommend opening a DOS prompt and running Python from there when you need interactive usage.  This will keep your two Python installs nicely separate (it can be very useful to have both; I do this on my own machine).  Also, you may have some problems running a program designed for Windows interactive console use from within a Cygwin shell.

Comment: Note: numpy can be installed directly from the Cygwin setup.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You're running a separate copy of python provided by cygwin.

You can run /cygdrive/c/python25/python (or wherever you installed it)
to get your win32 one, or just install another copy of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that PYTHONPATH has NumPy. Refer [The Module Search Path (section 6.1.2)](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/tut/node8.html) and [Modifying Python's Search Path (section 4.1)](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/inst/search-path.html).

Comment: Links are dead. It would be better if you write the steps here.

Answer (score 0):

numpy built for windows is not compatible with cygwin python. You have to build it by yourself on cygwin.

Comment: perhaps this was true in '09, but its available with the Cygwin package manager.